# How to enumerate a one column csv file using bash?

Tags: bash, shell, csv, terminal

I have a list like this

- 6.53143.S
- 6.47643.S
- 6.53161.S

dots are just for presentation

some bash scripting

1. 6.53143.S
2. 6.47643.S
3. 6.53161.s

Comment: Are dots for presentation or literal in the sample input ?

Comment: One column CSV is not a CSV.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
awk '{print NR, $0}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you only want to print the line numbers along with lines then use simple `cat` for the same.

```
cat -n Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

If your data actually looks like this:

```
 - 6.53143.S
 - 6.47643.S
 - 6.53161.S
```

use:

```
$ awk '$1=NR' file
1 6.53143.S
2 6.47643.S
3 6.53161.S
```